# PHP Keep the User's File Upload Path After Validation Fail

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-upload, filepath

i want to ask that if its possible to keep the user's upload path where he selects from his computer that which file will be uploaded like the path " C:\Users\User1\Desktop\1.jpg " , the reason i want to learn about this is after submitting forms with php when he fails about validation, i want him to not reselect it..

Summary : How can i save the path : C:\Users\User1\Desktop\1.jpg in user's form if user fails on other field's validation

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible. Only the filename is sent by the browser, not the full path.

Answer (score 1):

**First thoughts**

I am just posting this in case you think of doing something crazy like, why don't I use javascript or JS library to get the path?

It's a DOM element after all.

Well browsers are your enemy!! why? For security reasons, browsers have security restructions like as you have guessed don't expose the local file structure.

**Question**
What would you do with the file path?
How's a file path going to be handy on the server-side?

Hem, let me think...still thinking.....

The only purpose that I can think of is discovery before attempting a hacking.

Field validation can be an honest answer, but you can avoid this by creating a form that uses AJAX to submit the data to sever.

**What??**

Yes sir, use ajax submit the data as post, validate it and send a message back to the browser stating if the form was successfully submitted or not.

With ajax you don't leave the page when data is submitted to the server