# keep file input after send in php

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a form that is checked on server. If checking fails it redirect back to form and all values remain filled but the file input.

Is it possible to keep also this value filled?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839525/php-keep-the-value-of-file-fields-when-validating-a-form-returns-false?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839525/php-keep-the-value-of-file-fields-when-validating-a-form-returns-false?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159218/php-keep-the-users-file-upload-path-after-validation-fail?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858347/how-to-retain-file-input-value-after-form-submission-with-errors?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967916/how-to-keep-input-type-file-field-value-after-failed-validation-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You can achieve this by Submitting the form details for validation using an AJAX submission method so the user will not leaves the page if error occurs in the form. That way you can validate the result server-side but the user still has all their values populated, including file inputs.